# How to apply Procrustes transformation to a single point

Tags: linear-algebra, procrustes-problem

I guess this is probably a too simple question for most of you but my algebra skills are very limited (ashamed).

I have run two PCA analyses and conducted a Procrustes analyses to fit one matrix (first two components) onto the other matrix. As a result I obtain the transformed matrix but also: a rotation matrix, a translation vector and a scale factor.

How should I operate with these three elements (rotation, translation and scale) to translate the coordinates of a single point that is part of the matrix-to-be-transformed but was skipped from the Procrustes analyses? That point was excluded before the Procrustes analysis because I don't want it to have any influence on the fitting. 
(In case it helps, I am using the R package "vegan").

Many, many thanks,
Federico

Comment: Perhaps you should add some tags to attract people who (unlike me) know what a Procrustes analysis is.

Comment: The server didn't let me add the Procrustes tag. I have finally solved the problem though. Thanks for the advice